# How can I add characters to the end of a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to do something simple, but I'm struggling! The code below runs successfully (I included it all as figured it also might be useful to someone!), and all I want to do is to add some characters to the end of the file, after the second `for` loop. I have tried reusing the `fs.writeFileSync` as well as other fs options, but no success. Any advice?

```
const watson = require("../../src/api/WatsonSingleton.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const DATASETS_PATH = "./workspaces/";
const workspaceFilenames = ["workspace_abroad.json"];

let outputText = "[\n";

for(let filename of workspaceFilenames) { // Loop through filenames defined in `workspaceFilenames`
    let workspace = require(`${DATASETS_PATH}${filename}`);

    for(let intentDefinition of workspace.intents) { // Loop through intents to return examples
        let examples = intentDefinition.examples;

        for(let example of examples) {

            var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { // set promise to throttle tests so the next sendMessage occurs only after the previous sendMessage has returned a full response
                setTimeout(function() {
                               resolve(watson.sendMessage(example.text).catch(console.error));
                }, 2000);
            });

            promise1.then(function(res) { // Execute the promise and append response to a file
                outputText += "    " + JSON.stringify(res) + ",\n";
                console.log(res);
                fs.writeFileSync("../report/workspaces/" + filename, outputText); // Append report file with response data
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question? What is the expected and especially *current* behavior?

Comment: Adding a character to the end of the file, once the second for loop has finished, i.e. after "for(let intentDefinition of workspace.intents)".  Currently nothing happens, I am just trying the same fs.Writefile command again, after end of second loop, but no result.

Comment: e.g. fs.writeFileSync("../report/workspaces/" + filename, "{}]")

Comment: Does it event execute the `promise1.then` callback? What does `watson.sendMessage` return? If it's a promise you're resolving your promise with another one. In that case you might want to change it to `watson.sendMessage(example.text).then(resolve).catch(console.error));`.

Comment: Oh, I see where you are going with this :) Will try that and see. Wherever I put the fs.writeFileSync command for the final chars I want to add to the file, nothing happens. If I put the  outside all loop (I did this to check if command was doing anything at all) it just overwrites all content (which I expected, I was just checking line executes)

Comment: The line I am trying to add to the code above is (to make it valid JSON formay):  fs.writeFileSync("../report/workspaces/" + filename, "{}]);

Comment: If it's working outside the loop / promise, but not inside, it looks like the part is simply not executed. Could be anything, like there are no *intents* or *examples*, so the loops are simply skipped. Setting up a possible answer, give me a sec...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to throttle the loop by using a `setTimeout`, it won't work like that. The loop will continue to execute, since the setTimeout is non blocking, thus all requests will still be sent at once - after a 2 second delay. What you want to do is wait for `watson.sendMessage` to finish in each iteration. I'd used the async/await approach to make that happen.

This also allows a simpler code without the need to create a Promise. Your loops should look like this:

```
 // Loop through intents to return examples
for(let intentDefinition of workspace.intents) {
    intentDefinition.examples.forEach(async function() {
        try {
          const res = await watson.sendMessage(example.text);
          console.log(res);
          outputText += "    " + JSON.stringify(res) + ",\n";

          // Append report file with response data
          fs.writeFileSync("../report/workspaces/" + filename, outputText); 
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Not the answer I was expecting, but very very helpful!

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue I asked, as code ran without problems anyway, though appreciate the alternatives. So deleting the question, as life too short for stackoverflow these day, sigh!

Comment: Unfortunately can't delete, so will leave up.

Comment: Reminder of the actual question "How can I add characters to the end of a JSON file?".  Your code is nice, but it didn't fix the issue I posted.

Comment: I was told by others to avoid using forEach/beforeEach, as it can cause problems in loops. The recommendation I had was to use "for ... let ... of".  But sometimes it is just a matter of opinion ;)